# $V=W_1\oplus\cdots\oplus W_k$ if and only if $\dim(V)=\sum{\dim(W_i)}$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

If $W_1,\dots, W_k$ are subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ such that $W_1+\cdots+W_k=V$, and I want to show that $V=W_1\oplus\cdots\oplus W_k$ if and only if $\dim(V)=\sum{W_i}$, then will what's displayed below suffice?

---

$$V=W_1\oplus\cdots\oplus W_k$$
$$\iff$$
$$V=W_1+\cdots+W_k~\text{and}~W_i \cap (W_1 + \ldots + W_{i-1} + W_{i+1} + \ldots + W_k) = \{0\}$$
$$\iff$$
$$\text{The subspaces $W_i$ are independent; that is, no sum $w_1+\cdots+w_k$ with $w_i$ in $W_i$ is zero except the trivial sum.}$$
$$\iff$$
$${\scr{B}}=\{\beta_1,\dots,\beta_k\}~\text{is a basis for $V$, where $\beta_i$ is a basis for $W_i$}$$
$$\iff$$
$$\dim{V}=\dim{(W_1+\cdots+W_k)}=\dim{W_1}+\cdots+\dim{W_k}=~\mid\beta_1\mid+\cdots+\mid\beta_k\mid=k$$
$$\iff$$
$$\overset{\text{Does this belong here?}}{\dim{\scr{B}}=k}$$

Comment: you are supposing that $W_i$ $i\in {1,2,..,k}$ has dimension $1$ wich must not be true

Comment: Which denotes cardinality then?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  $|A|$ denotes the cardinality of set $A$.  If $\beta_i$ is a basis for $W_i$, then $|\beta_i|=\dim W_i$.

Comment: The second line shows a big misunderstanding of the direct sum... it is not equivalent to being a direct sum. For instance, suppose $A\cap B=\{0\}$. Then $A\cap A\cap B=\{0\}$ also but the sum of $A+A+B$ is *not* direct. The correct version is: $(\sum_{i\neq j} W_i)\cap W_j=\{0\}$.

Comment: Try to reduce your usage of notation. In particular avoid using $\iff$ between statements that are *not* strictly equivalent. **None** of the equivalences in your post actually is an equivalence of mathematical statements.

Comment: @Martin So what about this?

Answer (score 5):

Your first equivalence is false: when $k \geq 3$, $\bigcap_{i=1}^k W_k = \{0\}$ is too weak to imply that the spaces $W_1,\ldots,w_k$ are **independent**, i.e., that $W_1 + \ldots + W_k = W_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus W_k$.  For example, take $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, $W_1 = \langle (1,0) \rangle$, $W_2 = \langle (0,1) \rangle$, $W_3 = \langle (1,1) \rangle$.  This is one of two or three subtle traps in linear algebra that even professional mathematicians can fall into if they're not careful.

Any of the following is an acceptable definition of independent subspaces (and they are equivalent):

(i) For all $1 \leq i \leq k$, $W_i \cap (W_1 + \ldots + W_{i-1} + W_{i+1} + \ldots + W_k) = \{0\}$.
(ii) If for all $i$ we choose a nonzero $v_i \in W_i$, then $\{v_1,\ldots,v_k\}$ is a linearly independent set.
(iii) If for all $i$ we choose a linearly independent set $S_i \subset W_i$, then 
$S = \bigcup_{i=1}^k S_i$ is a linearly independent set.

Note that if you believe that (iii) is equivalent to the sum being a direct sum then you've got the equivalence you're asking about, so I suggest you concentrate instead on showing these conditions are equivalent to your given definition of internal direct sums.

Comment: So what about this then?

Comment: @Barisa: your new version is improved.  If you take your first $\iff$ as the definition of the sum being direct, it seems to me that you should explain why the third $\iff$ holds (it's hard for me to evaluate the second $\iff$ because I don't know which definition of "independent subspaces" you're taking).  If that $\iff$ can be taken as known, then your argument is essentially complete.

Comment: What about now?