# Prove that $V$ is the direct sum of $W_1, W_2 ,\dots , W_k$ if and only if $\dim(V) = \sum_{i=1}^k \dim W_i$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W_1,\dots,W_k$ be a subspace of a finite dimensional vector space $V$ such that the $\sum_{i=1}^k W_i = V$.

> Prove: $V$ is the direct sum of $W_1, W_2 , \dots, W_k$ if and only $\dim(V) = \sum_{i=1}^k \dim W_i$.

Comment: I assume $\mathrm{dirn}(V)$ means $\mathrm{dim}(V)$? Anyway, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: yes sir haha dirn(V) is dim(V). My problem is exactly where to begin...I was thinking of showing two directions: 
"->"Assuming V is a direct sum of Wi that there exist an ordered basis bi for all Wi and that if all bi are added together than there elements equal the number of elements of V and therefore showing the equal dimensions
"<-" Assuming that dim(V) = sum(dim( Wi )) 
Well I guess it would be a similar argument that all the elements of the basis of Wi add up to the number of elements of the basis V...

Though I am not sure how to properly display this or if its right?

Comment: If $\mathrm{dirn}(V)$ does mean $\dim(V)$, this would make a funny typo. The OP is perhaps a human-flesh optical character recognition machine!

Comment: I unfortunately (or more likely fortunately) am not a human-flesh optical char. recog. machine haha...just copy pasted from an email to a friend

Comment: This was recently discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/399592/49437)

Comment: I just want to mention that the case $k=2$ follows in particular immediately from the formula $\dim (F+G)=\dim F+\dim G-\dim (F\cap G)$. One can start an induction from there, but that's not the shortest path.

Comment: @julien I actually saw a proof going that way and it seemed more confusing and I want something a little simpler until I grasp the concept of direct sums

Comment: @martin Thank you that post helped a lot

Comment: Yes, like I said, that's not the shortest path. But the formula I mention has some interest.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dimensions of vector subspaces in a direct sum are additive](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395130/dimensions-of-vector-subspaces-in-a-direct-sum-are-additive)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define $\ \ B_i$ a basis of $ \ \ W_i\ \ $  for $\ \ i \in {1,..,k } $. Since sum( $W_i$)$= V$ we know that  $\bigcup_{i=1}^k B_i$ is a spanning list of $V$.

Now we add the condition : sum dim($B_i$)$=$sum dim($W_i$)$=$dim($V$).

This means that $\bigcup_{i=1}^k B_i$ is a basis. (Spanning list of $V$ with same dimension).

Can you conclude from here the direct sum property?

If we define Basises as before and we know that $W_i$ is a direct sum can you conclude ( knowing that sum( $W_i$)$= V$ , wich is given)  that $\ \ \bigcup_{i=1}^k B_i$ is a Basis of $V$?

Comment: I would then conclude that by the TFAE of a theorem in our text that this is equivalent to the direct sum property? I read over the proof of this explanation (why B1 U B2 U ... U Bk is a basis of V) and that makes sense for the direction assuming dim(V)=sum( dim(Wi)) for i from 1 to k. Though is this sufficient for the other direction of Assuming V to be a direct sum of Wi for i from 1 to k too? Sorry if these questions are remedial, kinda new to all this. If any tips toward perspective, I am open to them.

Comment: Yes your conclusion is correct. The other direction starts with the sentence " If we define Basises as before and we know that $W_i$...". You then should be able to conclude that sum($B_i$) is a basis of $V$. This is equivalent to  saying : $\dim(V) = \sum_{i=1}^k \dim W_i$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, this makes a lot more sense now. I will try putting the proof together and if I have any more questions come back to this thread.

Comment: Note that $B_i$ is a basis, not the basis, on your first line.  And on your third paragraph, this means that $\bigcup_{i=1}^k B_i$ is a basis. Also sum $(B_i)$ is not a very good notation when you mean union, I think.

Comment: I think you mean the sum of the dimension of the span of $B_i $ is the dimension of $W_i $.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** Finite dimensional vector spaces are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension.

**Hint 2:** What is the dimension of $W_{1}\oplus W_{2}$?

Comment: The first hint makes a lot of sense...if I am not mistaken then if V is the direct sum of W1,..,Wk then I can prove they are isomorphic and therefore there dimensions are equal.

For the second hint I am not sure. I am pretty new to direct sums, I have read over my notes and as I understand it W1+...+Wk is the smallest subspace of V that contains W1 or W2 or ... or Wk. From that understanding I would say that the dimensions is 2?

Comment: It depends on the dimension of the W_i's.  For example, if W_1 has dimension 4 then W_1 \oplus W_2 cannot possibly have dimension 2. Do you know what the dimension of W_1 + W_2 is?